# image sometimes can upload in the folder in codeigniter but sometimes not

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have a weird problem, I'm doing upload an image using codeigniter, but the thing was weird. it save to the database but part of them can upload to the specific folder, and the other not. Can someone help me ? I'm using Codeigniter 3 and PHP 7.3.13

this is my controller :

```
public function edit_pegawai($id_pegawai){
    if (isset($_POST['simpan'])){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'Nama', 'required');
            $data_pegawai=array(
                'nik'=> $this->input->post('nik'),
                'nama'=> $this->input->post('nama')
            );
            $data['dataPegawai'] = $data_pegawai;

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
                $img = $this->UserModel->get_foto($id_pegawai)->row();
                $image = $img->foto;

                if ($_FILES['foto']['name']){
                    if ($image != NULL){ 
                        unlink('./assets/img/foto/'.$image);
                    }
                    $nama = ucwords(strtolower($this->input->post('nama')));
                    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/foto/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpe|jpg|jpeg';
                    $config['max_size'] = 10000;
                    $config['file_name'] = $nama;
                    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
                    $this->load->library('upload');
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                    if ($_FILES['foto']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['foto']['type'] == 'image/png' || $_FILES['foto']['type'] != 'image/jpg'){

                        $this->upload->do_upload('foto');
                        $hilihh = $this->upload->data();
                        $foto = $hilihh['file_name'];
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_gagal');
                        redirect(site_url('listpegawai'));
                    }
                    $this->db->update('pns_local', $data_pegawai, array('id_pegawai'=>$id_pegawai));
                    $this->db->set('foto', $foto);
                    $this->db->where('id_pegawai', $id_pegawai);
                    $this->db->update('pns_local');
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_berhasil');
                    redirect(site_url('listpegawai'));
                }
```

and this is my view

```
<form method="POST" action="<?= site_url('listpegawai/edit_pegawai/'.$dataPegawai['id_pegawai'])?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input hidden type="text" name="id_pegawai" value="<?php echo $dataPegawai['id_pegawai']; ?>">
<div class="card bg-light">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>NIK </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nik" value="<?php echo $dataPegawai['nik'];?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Nama Lengkap </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama" value="<?php echo $dataPegawai['nama'];?>">
        </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
          <label>Foto <span style="color: red">*</span></label><br>
          <?php
          if ($dataPegawai['foto'] != NULL){
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/foto/'.$dataPegawai['foto'])?>" width="85" height="100">
          <?php }
          else{
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/foto/default.png')?>" width="85" height="100">
          <?php }
          ?>
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" name="foto" accept="image/*"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
     <button type="submit" name="simpan" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Simpan Data
      </button>
     </div>
    </form>
```

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

Set $config['log_threshold'] = 4; and see the CI logs in application/logs/

Php logs can also help.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try taking ./ out of your upload path

Comment: I've tried this too yesterday but the problem still same